# Why can't I save an SQL database on the server itself?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to set up an SQL server for my web-server to send and receive data from. I'm somewhat confused on how the whole SQL server thing works though. I was wondering why I need a separate server for my SQL and my web server. why can't I save an SQL database on the server itself instead and access it the same way one would read and write an XML or JSON file on the server to store data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be getting caught up with server, as in the computer its running on (physical box, virtual machine, might be easier to think of it as the operating system) vs the server, as in web server/sql server which are different software packages.

So the SQL server (software) and the Web server (software) can run on the same server (hardware, essentially).

Depending on your use case its usually best to have the SQL server on a different server (hardware) to your web server so that there is more dedicated resources for their processes, but its not required.

If you are asking why you cant talk to the database file directly, (in the case of MS SQL Server, at least) the server manages its own permissions and manages all the file IO for you. Its a bit more complicated than a JSON file.

Comment: I'm not hosting my server locally but bought web space and upload and download files through FTP, would i also upload an SQL database program through FTP and if so what directory would one upload it to, Root i presume?

Comment: Ah, that will depend on your hosting environment. If you are using MS Access you might be able to do just that, as that isn't strictly a 'server'. Some hosting environments will have their own SQL servers which you can attach your database to. It may pay to contact them as see how they would like you to do that